# What does `from x import x` actually mean?

Tags: python, import

I mean, this very formula can mean different things whether there is a package named `x`, whether there is a module named `x`, whether there is a variable named `x` in one of them etc.

I did not find an easy-to-understand, concise answer to this question, not even in the `python` documentation.

The answer would shed light on how python `import` work.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is pretty much correct, but here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> The `from` form uses a slightly more complex process:
>
> 1. find the module specified in the `from` clause, loading and initializing it if necessary;
> 2. for each of the identifiers specified in the `import` clauses:
>
>    1. check if the imported module has an attribute by that name
>    2. if not, attempt to import a submodule with that name and then check the imported module again for that attribute
>    3. if the attribute is not found, `ImportError` is raised.
>    4. otherwise, a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace, using the name in the as clause if it is present, otherwise
>       using the attribute name

Comment: Thanks! Hm.. 2.2 above seems to be incomplete and somewhat contradictory to what I found. It found that 1) it does not "check the imported module again for that attribute" just import the module; and 2) it first checks whether there is a package `x` and only after this whether there is a module `x.py` which is a useful additional info, I guess.

Comment: @BálintSass so, all packages are modules. In the above description, packages and modules are equivalent.

Comment: @BálintSass yes, I'm actually not entirely sure what is being referred to in 2.2.

Comment: @juanpaarrivillaga 2.2 refers to the second point of the second point in the documentation snippet cited by you. :)

Comment: @juanpaarrivillaga "all packages are modules" Hm.. As I see it, _package_ `x` is a directory named `x` with a `__init__.py` file in it, while _module_ `x` is a `x.py` file. My observation is: if both are present, the package _is_ preferred by `import`.

Answer (score 0):

I use these notions below: `package x` is a directory called `x` with an `__index__.py` file in it; `module x` is a `x.py` file.
After a significant amount of testing I came to the following.

```
from x import x
```

means:
(pseudocode)

```
if there is a package x:
    if there is a variable x in x/__init__.py: import this variable
    elif there is a package x in package x: import this inner package
    elif there is a module x.py in package x: import this module
    else: ImportError
elif there is module x.py:
    if there is a variable x in x.py: import this variable
    else: ImportError
else: ImportError
```

This algorithm seems to be correct.
Tested on python 3.7.6

Answer (score -1):

When you use `import`, the whole file is being imported as an class. If you have a module (file) named `sum` and inside this file you have a function called `sum`, using `from sum import sum` you get you only the function.